# Modify global variable Ant

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I want to change "variable" in Ant file, in one target and see that change in another target.

```
<variable name="foo" value="hello" />
<target name="print-me">
    <echo message="${foo}" />
    <antcall target="change-me" />
    <echo message="${foo}" />
</target>

<target name="change-me">
    <variable name="foo" value="world" />
</target>
```

While I want it to print: 'hello , world' , it prints 'hello, hello'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to over-write the property in ant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866729/how-to-over-write-the-property-in-ant)

Comment: you forgot unset="true" in the [variable task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use :

```
<target name="change-me">
    <variable name="foo" unset="true"/>
    <variable name="foo" value="world"/>
</target>
```

as Oers already mentioned in his comment to your question or use a more
straightforward approach with the `let task` of [Ant addon Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) :

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">

...
<!-- overwrite any existing property or userproperty
     (those properties defined on the commandline via -Dfoo=bar ..) --> 
<fl:let> foo ::= 'world'</fl:let>

...
</project>
```

Comment: the variable unset does not effect the variable outside of target. meaning if I add this change, the print in "print-me" target still prints "hello"... I'll try this add-on and let you know. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This will work if you use the ant-contrib tags.

Comment: You might want to give an example to illustrate your answer.