# Override fileset ref in ANT

Tags: ant, overriding, intersect, fileset

I have populated a fileset at the start of script as follows;

```
<!-- Define the list of projects to be built -->
<fileset id="ivy.buildlist.fileset" dir="${ivy.buildlist.dir}" includes="${ivy.buildlist.includes}" excludes="${ivy.buildlist.excludes}" />
```

But I want to update this ref if user select a particular task. For that I have written a new target with `<intersect>` which will be called but its not updating the reference;

```
<target name="getPreReleaseList" description="Target to override the component list for pre release" >
    <echo message="Existing List : ${toString:ivy.buildlist.fileset}" />
    <intersect>
        <fileset refid="ivy.buildlist.fileset" />
        <fileset dir="${ivy.buildlist.dir}" 
            includes="${ivy.pre.buildlist.includes}"
            excludes="${ivy.pre.buildlist.excludes}" />
    </intersect>
    <echo message="Updated List : ${toString:ivy.buildlist.fileset}" />
</target>
```

Before and after list in `ivy.buildlist.fileset` is same :(. Am I missing anything or do I have adapt a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to the fact that ant properties are **immutable**.

In order to modify a property, you could either use the [variable task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html) or use a macrodef.

I suggest you take a look at [the following question for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866729/how-to-over-write-the-property-in-ant).