# ANT- How to recursively build the iOS project for different environments?

Tags: ios, ant, build-automation

I am using ANT script to automate my iOS build and packaging tasks. As per my current build script, I am passing the desired environment from command line and the script will generate a IPA file for that particular environment.

Basically, it will run the following targets- `ValidateParameters, SetupBuildProperties, SetupXcodeSettings, clean, archive & package.`

I have to create builds for `Dev, QA & UAT`. So, I have to run the script 3 times to have 3 different IPA files. When I pass the environment from command line, I store the same in a ANT property and that will be used in almost all the targets. Because, a property is immutable, that doesn't help me either.

**Now, is there any way I can generate all the 3 builds by running the script only once?** Not sure how to reset the environment property !!

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create a target called something like "buildForAllEnvs" where you invoke a subproject build using [`antcall`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html) for each target environment and passing its property as a nested element:

```
<target name="buildForAllEnvs">
    <antcall target="runBuild">
        <param name="targetEnv" value="Dev"/>
    </antcall>
    <antcall target="runBuild">
        <param name="targetEnv" value="QA"/>
    </antcall>
    <antcall target="runBuild">
        <param name="targetEnv" value="UAT"/>
    </antcall>
</target>
```

Note that there are many ways to override or reset properties in Ant. See [How to over-write the property in Ant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866729/how-to-over-write-the-property-in-ant):

1. Using Ant-Contrib's [`var`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html) task (requires adding Ant-Contrib to your classpath, which also introduces a bunch of useful tasks for conditional execution using `if` and looping using `for`).
2. Using macrodefs to reuse the same build with different parameters.
3. Manually overriding the property using the project API (hacky though).